# Is it better to reuse FormGroup vs new FormGroup in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

Are there benefits of doing this:

```
  export class ContactComponent implements OnInit { 

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({ 
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(40)]],
    });
  }

  onFormChange(contact: Contact) {
   this.form.controls['email'].setValue(contact.email);
   this.form.controls['name'].setValue(contact.name);
  }
```

Over this:

```
  export class ContactComponent implements OnInit { 

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  onFormChange(contact: Contact) {
   this.form = new FormGroup({
            email: new FormControl(contact.email),
            name: new FormControl(contact.name),
    });
  }
```

I assume it is expensive to declare new repeatedly but I couldn't find any answers?

Comment: The second case is not clear enough for me, first, you have `formBuilder` injected, you are not even using it... second, you don't have a initialization for your form object, third, why would you want to create a form each time `onFormChange` is called?, in the first case, you at least have a constant form object which you can use in any part of the component class...

Comment: the question is, what do you want to achieve in your component..., what's the goal?

Comment: Would be great if you can specify the goal, what you try to attempt. From my perspective, it just looks like you just try to perform patching value to the form. So either you can use the provided API to patch the value to control or patch the object to form, for example: `this.form.patchValue(/* object */)`. Recreating a `FormGroup` instance is unnecessary, for example in real life (this may not relevant), you want to change the wheel from the car, you just change the wheel rather than re-build/buy the car. But of course, it depends on your goals.